# explain("executionStats") with aggregate not working in mongoose

Tags: mongoose

To test my aggregate's query performance in mongoose 5.5.4 (current latest version), then I call

```
User.explain("executionStats").aggregate([]);
```

It invokes a "User.explain is not a function" error unexpectly because it is working in mongodb shell with these results.

```
db.getCollection('users').explain("allPlansExecution").aggregate([
    {$match: {"categories.dotoris._id": ObjectId("5cbfbdd5a23e14127c603a1a")}},
    {$project:{_id:1, "categories._id":1, "categories.dotoris":1}}])
```

> Result
>   [image]

---

After I search mongoose docs, I found that I can use following function

```
User.aggregate([]).explain("executionStats")
```

But It has only queryPlanner information but executionStats.

How can I get executionStats information with aggregate in mongoose?

Comment: did you tried this : `User.aggregate([]).explain("executionStats")` ?  what you are expecting in result?

Comment: @Vikash Singh - Yes. Its result just have query, queryPlanner, etc but not executionStats.

Answer (score 0):

In mongoose-6.2 there is option verbosity https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/blob/6.2/lib/aggregate.js#L717

`Aggregate.prototype.explain = function(verbosity, callback) {`

There is no way to get `executionStats` with mongoose < 6.2 and `aggreate` https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/blob/6.1/lib/aggregate.js#L703. But we can turn on profiling and get pipeline parsed from command field:

```
db.getProfilingStatus(); db.setProfilingLevel(0); db.system.profile.drop(); db.createCollection("system.profile", {capped: true, size:10485760 }); db.setProfilingLevel(2); db.getProfilingStatus();
var pipeline = [...];
var exp = db.getCollection('orders').explain('executionStats').aggregate(pipeline);
db.system.profile.find({"ns" : "shop.orders"})
print(JSON.stringify(exp));
// To have streamlined output:
// git clone https://github.com/gharriso/MongoDBPerformanceTuningBook
load('/path/to/MongoDBPerformanceTuningBook/mongoTuning.js');
mongoTuning.aggregationExecutionStats(exp);
```